# Qt - Mysterious segfaults on worker thread

Tags: qt, segmentation-fault, symbian, qthread

I'm instantiating QSystemDeviceInfo on a worker thread, but it causes a segfault.

```
int BatteryInfo::getLevel() {
   QSystemDeviceInfo sysDevInfo; //segfault happens when I step on to this line
   return sysDevInfo.batteryLevel();
}
```

Is the class thread-safe, or does the problem lie elsewhere?

**EDIT: With further debugging I also noticed that native Symbian calls segfault as well.**

Best regards

Comment: Have you a panic code from the native calls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me and my friend found this issue as well on Symbian Qt Mobilty 1.0. He reported an issue [QtMobility access from multiple threads](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTMOBILITY-1058). As it says in the issue description *Think this could be due to that some static members are created first time the QSystemDeviceInfo/QSystemNetworkInfo is created.*.

If you are using Qt Mobility 1.2 or only accessing QSystemDeviceInfo from one thread it's some other issue.

EDIT: One workaround for us was to make sure we created a QSystemDeviceInfo object in our main thread first but then we had some problems with not getting all signals.

Comment: I'm using mobility 1.1, so this seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have capabilities set ?
QSystemDeviceInfo needs the 'ReadDeviceData' capability.You will need to sign your app to install on the device if you include this capability.

Comment: I have the capability set. Those calls work just fine without the thread. I have also signed the app.

Comment: I had a similar issue with QtContacts. Try initializing QSystemDeviceInfo on a heap in the main thread and then try using it in the worker thread.