# Why are seg faults happening when Qt is called from another thread?

Tags: multithreading, qt

I'm trying to use this api from a thread other than the main OS thread
 QtMobility::QSystemDisplayInfo::colorDepth

crashes every time. Is there a way to make calls like this off the main thread?

Comment: Maybe related to this question/answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/6841611/31044. Stressing the "maybe" :)

Comment: Have you tried linking against the debug version? That is likely to give you more context (and perhaps trigger assertions) as to why the crash is happening.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with Qt on the desktop, anything that required the GUI or information from the underlying GUI subsystem (whether it was Windows, OS X, or X11) was best left to run on the main thread. As per the comment (and the linked SO question therein), you could attempt to instantiate a `QtMobility::QSystemDisplayInfo` object on the main thread first and use it in a worker thread. However, I've learned to stick with the "only do GUI stuff in the main thread" rule.